# C++: How to set an element of enum to infinite?

Tags: c++, enums

i would like to generate an enum with one element set to inifite. I know about the limits library, but it seems this can only be used for specific datatypes.
Yet i would like to use it in enum:

```
enum Speedlimits{
  schoolarea = 30;
  normalarea = 50;
  highway = inifite;
};
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you want to set it to infinite?

Comment: 299792458 m/s ... not only a good idea, it's the law.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ has no notion of `infinite` (well, at least not in `enum` context - in math context there's [std::numeric_limits::infinity](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/infinity)). You'll have to settle for setting the value of `highway` to some magic number (like `-42` or whatever won't be normally used) and then treat that number as meaning "infinite" in your client code..
Or maybe find a way to represent things where you don't *need* infinite.